# Truffle migration of an ownable contract

Tags: truffle, ganache, truffle-migration

Initially, I deploy everything using REMIX IDE, currently I would like to try to deploy a contract that is ownable into local ganache blockchain using truffle migration:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract A is Ownable {
     constructor() Ownable(msg.sender) {}
}
```

Previously, there is no constructor implemented when using remix IDE. But here, due to error below, I tried to add constructor.

> TypeError: No arguments passed to the base constructor. Specify the arguments or mark "A" as abstract.
> [image]

Should this migration code be correct? Because I need to have an argument for the Ownable constructor?

```
var A = artifacts.require("A");

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    const deployerAddress = accounts[0];
    await deployer.deploy(A, deployerAddress);
  };
```

or

```
var A = artifacts.require("A");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(A);
};
```

Here is the configuration (using ganache interface): [image]